# How to move all files in current folder to subfolder?

Tags: files

I am at the path:

```
/myuser/downloads/
```

And I create a sub folder:

```
/myuser/downloads/new
```

Now I want to move all files and folders/sub-folders in the downloads folder to the sub-folder.

how can I do this?

I tried:

```
mv -R *.* new/
```

But move doesn't take the -R switch it seems.

Comment: You do not need -R. Just `mv * new` Though, it will whine "cannot move new to new" or something similar. Perhaps `mv -i * new` to you prevent overwrites.

Answer (score 165, accepted):

The command

```
mv !(new) new
```

should do the trick. If it doesn't work, run `shopt -s extglob` first.

To also move hidden files/directories (that beginning with a dot), run also `shopt -s dotglob` first.
So, to sum up:

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
mv !(new) new
shopt -u dotglob
```

(It is always better to unset `dotglob` to avoid bad surprises with `shopt -u dotglob`)

Comment: can you mention what is the significance of ``!(something)`` ?

Comment: @adeer that is just saying not(something). In other words, copy everything but not something. Clear as mud?

Comment: very. do you happen to know the equivalent for zsh ?

Comment: I don't get it, e.g. what If I try to move the content of the folder `dev` to my current location, do I have to execute `mv !(dev) dev` ?? I get `-bash: !: event not found`

Comment: @adeer very similar. `setopt extendedglob` to set the extended glob mode in zsh. `^` is the exclusion symbol, so `mv ^new new` would do the trick. then to see all the options set in zsh you can use `setopt` and to disable extended glob mode you can do `unsetopt extendedglob`

Comment: @Mr.T I'm running `zsh` and I tried what you said with the `^` character and didn't get a result yet. Thanks for the info regarding the `^` though.

Comment: It somehow does not work with a full path in the `!(...)` statement. I made it work by `cd`ing into the superfolder. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: The equivalent ZSH command would be as follows: `setopt extendedglob; mv ^new(D) new unsetopt extendedglob`. `^` negates the `new` pattern, and `(D)` includes dot files. See the [docs](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) for more information.

Answer (score 27):

I found something like this but is a bit simpler to understand, and it might work well for you too:

```
ls | grep -v new | xargs mv -t new
```

Adding an explanation to the above solution:

From man pages:

- `mv -t`

  ```
  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY
        move all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY
  ```
- `grep -v`

  ```
  -v, --invert-match
        Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
  ```

Explained by step:

- `ls` will list the files in current directory
- `grep -v new` will return piped to that is not match new
- `xargs mv -t new` will move the files piped to it from `grep -v` to the target directory

Comment: I tried this method but I am getting: `mv: illegal option -- t`. Is this because I am using `zsh`?

Comment: @ConstantFun It could be zsh but I would guess it's your implementation of `mv`, (meaning your version of mv is different them what I was using) what os are you using? I believe when I wrote this answer I was on linux distro `centos` using `bash`.

Comment: Just testing this on osx and I get the same error `mv: illegal option -- t` which is because osx's mv does not have a `-t` option.

Comment: (I have not tried this, and don't plan on it.) This link https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/69223/how-to-replace-mac-os-x-utilities-with-gnu-core-utilities tells you how to install the gnucore which should help you get gnu core cli utils, osx ships with bsd cli tools which are different the the ones that come with linux.

Comment: I am on OSX running `zsh`, so it is probably the OS then..? Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: Thanks, I was just missing the  ```- t``` in my command

Comment: -t is not valid in shell. Trying in docker alpine image. mv says it has only -f -i and -n

Comment: @TheFool that is because Alpine linux uses busybox and the busybox implementation of mv does not have `-t` as an option.
https://github.com/brgl/busybox/blob/master/coreutils/mv.c

Comment: Ah, thanks for the info.

Comment: this does not move secret files (eg - files that start with . like .gitignore. 
Use `ls -A | ...` to also include hidden files and folder.

Answer (score 21):

### Just use `mv * subdir1` and ignore the warning.

You can just use `mv * subdir1`. You will see a warning message relating to trying to move `subdir1` into itself, like this:

```bsh
mv: cannot move 'subdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, 'subdir1/subdir1'
```

But it will move all of the other files and directories to `subdir1` correctly.

An example:

```bsh
$ ls
$ mkdir dir1 dir2 dir3      
$ touch file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
$ mkdir subdir1
$ ls
#=> dir1  dir2  dir3  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  subdir1
$ mv * subdir1
#=> mv: cannot move 'subdir1' to a subdirectory of itself, 'subdir1/subdir1'
$ ls
#=> subdir1
$ ls subdir1
#=> dir1  dir2  dir3  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt
```

Comment: If you really don't like the warning (maybe this is in a bigger script where the warning would be confusing), `mv * subdir1 2>/dev/null`. This is not always desirable, though, since there might be other errors reported by mv (e.g. if you don't have permissions).

Comment: this does not move secret files (eg - files that start with `.` like `.gitignore`

Comment: @NotSoShabby Interesting! Thanks for posting. I didn't even think of that. Any idea how those can be included as well?

Comment: @NotSoShabby You can use `mv * .* subdir1` to move all hidden and non-hidden files into `subdir1`.

Answer (score 11):

Simple idea. Assuming you are in */myuser*, rename *downloads* to *new*, create a new *downloads* directory then move *new* into it.

```
mv downloads new # downloads is now called new
mkdir downloads # create new directory downloads
mv new downloads # move new into it.
```

Comment: Really nice idea. Simple and works!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move all the files from a folder to one of its subfolders you can use the following command:

```
find /myuser/downloads/ -type d -name 'new' -prune -type f | xargs mv -t /myuser/downloads/new
```

It will find all the files and then move them to your subfolder.

@waltinator: added `-type d -name 'new' -prune` to prevent traversal of `/myuser/downloads/new`.

Comment: I created  a subdirectory named `new` and tried this command, I get `mv: missing file operand` and `Try 'mv --help' for more information`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this alternative process –– remain in the path

```
/myuser/downloads/
```

but, instead of first creating the `/myuser/downloads/new/` directory, instead create a folder in the `/myuser/` directory, with the command `mkdir ../new`, then move all the files in `downloads` to `new`, and finally move `new` into `downloads`. You can do this in one line, while in the `/myuser/downloads/` path, with the command:

```
mkdir ../new && mv * ../new && mv ../new ../downloads
```

In this case, you don't have to worry about any sort of "filtering" of files/folders, since `new` is on the same level of the path as `downloads`, so you can just move everything in `downloads` to `new`, and then move `new` into downloads`.

However, if you already have the subfolder `new` created and don't want to create another one, not to worry –– just change the `mkdir` command on the left-hand side of the first `&&` in the command shown above to an `mv` command, pushing `new` up in the path; in other words, while you're still in `/myuser/downloads/`, you can change `mkdir ../new` to `mv new ..`. Then the subfolder `new` [in the path `/myuser/downloads/new/`] gets pushed up to `/myuser/new/`, at the same level as `/myuser/downloads/`, and then you can run the rest of the command as it is shown above. All together, we have, starting from the path `/myuser/downloads/`:

```
mv new .. && mv * ../new && mv ../new ../downloads
```

and, since you wanted to "move all files and folders/sub-folders in the downloads folder to the sub-folder [`new`]", you're done! If you had wanted to move *only* files (or *only* folders or [insert more granular object movement]), then you'd have to use other commands that can "filter" objects, such as `grep`. The commands written above are sufficient for your purposes, though.

Comment: If the new folder is nested like `CONTEXT_PATH=/foo/bar/baz` then this wont work I guess. I had same idea but I put  `mv $(echo "$CONTEXT_PATH" | cut -d/ -f1-2)" /some/`   in the mix.