# How to move all files to a sub-folder

Tags: command-line, files

I need to move files from a folder to a subfolder and this is a process that can be executed more than once, so the subfolder may not be empty.

Let's say the structure is as follows:

```
renatospaka@dell-w10home:~/devlpm$ ls -la
total 24
drwxr-xr-x  4 renatospaka renatospaka 4096 Sep  8 12:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 10 renatospaka renatospaka 4096 Sep  8 12:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 renatospaka renatospaka 4096 Sep  8 12:36 api
-rw-r--r--  1 renatospaka renatospaka   10 Sep  8 12:36 file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 renatospaka renatospaka   10 Sep  8 12:36 file2.txt
drwxr-xr-x  2 renatospaka renatospaka 4096 Sep  8 12:34 new
```

There is this excellent [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91740/how-to-move-all-files-in-current-folder-to-subfolder) from which I extracted the following command: `ls | grep -v new | xargs mv -t new`. It really works and moves the content to the **new** folder. However, from the 2nd execution on, an error pops up because the destination folder is not empty and the process abends.

How to fix this problem? I've tried some flag combinations on `xargs` but all failed...

Answer (score 1):

`mv` complains because it does not get any arguments from `xargs`. Add `-r` to prevent `xargs` from executing if the input is empty:

```
   -r, --no-run-if-empty
          If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is  no  in‐
          put.  This option is a GNU extension.
```

Also, you can control `mv` behavior when destination exists:

See `man mv`:

```
   -f, --force
          do not prompt before overwriting

   -i, --interactive
          prompt before overwrite

   -n, --no-clobber
          do not overwrite an existing file
```

So:

```
... |  xargs -r mv -f -t new
```

---

However, your command has serious problems when there are newlines or even spaces in your files. In general, [do not parse output of `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead).

Comment: I tested "... |  xargs -r mv -f -t new" and even so it returns the following error:

renatospaka@dell-w10home:~/devlpm$ ls | grep -v new | xargs -r mv -f -t new
mv: cannot move 'api' to 'new/api': Directory not empty

Comment: Regarding "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -f -t new {} +", it generated a completely unexpected result, so I need to read more about this. BTW, I just changed ".maxdepth 1" to ".maxdepth 5"

Comment: I executed the command "find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec mv -f -t  new {} +" but it doesn't work. It copies files but out of subfolders, at the end all files stay in "new" folder, no matter how the "maxdepth" is set. The structure I am copying is 4 degrees depth