# When moving all files but-one using mv, how do you escape filenames with dashes?

Tags: bash, mv

In [How to move all files in current folder to subfolder?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91740/how-to-move-all-files-in-current-folder-to-subfolder), the solution to moving all files from a folder but one is:

```
mv (!dontmovethis) /new/path/
```

When trying to move a file that includes a dash, a way to achieve this is:

```
mv -- '-dashie-file-' /new/path/
```

But what is the correct solution?

1. If `/new/path/` contains dashes: `/new/-dash-path/`
2. If `dontmovethis` contains dashes: `-dont-move-this`.
3. Both.

Naïvely trying out

```
mv -v -- (!'file-with-dash') '/new/path/with-dashes/'
```

produces the cryptic message (the `-v` is just to make `mv` more verbose):

```
bash: !'file: event not found
```

So this might be because `bash` is capturing the `!` character. But, when escaped for bash;

```
mv -v -- (\!'file-with-dash') '/new/path/with-dashes/'
mv -v -- (\\!'file-with-dash') '/new/path/with-dashes/'
mv -v -- (\\\\!'file-with-dash') '/new/path/with-dashes/'
mv -v -- (\!file-with-dash) /new/path/with-dashes/
```

(Just trying out some ideas in confusion of how many layers of escaping are needed), all of these produce this:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Which leads me to believe `mv` is not de-escaping the full filename the same way when applying the `!` operator. And finally, something like:

```
mv -v \(\!file-with-dash\) '/new/path/with-dashes'
mv -v \(\!'file-with-dash'\) '/new/path/with-dashes'
```

Produces:

```
mv: cannot stat '(!file-with-dash)': No such file or directory
```

Which means the `(` is being escaped *too much*: `mv` is looking for a file *literally* named `(!file-with-dash)`, while I want it to look for `file-with-dash`.

By the way, the second answer from that post *can* be easily adapted;

```
ls | grep -v dashing-file | xargs mv -t /new/dashing-folder
```

works straight away. There's one caveat to this method: If there's another file named `dashing-file-with-evil-secrets` that, being not the actual `dashing-file`, thus needs to be moved, gets caught by the `grep`. So it's not an exactly correct solution.

I just wonder if the top answer (the first code block in this post) can as well, as it does not have that caveat. Have not figured out a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax for the ksh-style extended glob is `!(pattern)` not `(!pattern)`

To exclude a the single file named `-dashie-file-` it would be `!(-dashie-file-)`, or to exclude **all** files containing dashes you would use `!(*-*)`, for example

```
mv !(-dashie-file-) path/to/newdir/

mv !(*-*) path/to/newdir/
```

You don't even need `--` since the shell excludes the troublesome files *before* `mv` sees them (although it's good practice to include it), ex. given

```
$ ls
 -dashie-file-   dashing-file-with-evil-secrets  'other file'   somefile
```

then using `ls` in place of `mv` for the purpose of illustration

```
$ ls !(-dashie-file-)
 dashing-file-with-evil-secrets  'other file'   somefile

$ ls !(*-*)
'other file'   somefile
```